# Create data frame with multple headings per column and populate data frame in loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I want to create a Pandas dataframe with multiple headings per column, and populate the data frame row by row with data in loop. I have created dataframes before, but this seems very complex for what I really want to do, and I do not know where to start.

Example:

```
step = list(range(1,5))
    for i in step:
        time = -2
        for j in range(0,5): # Time goes from -2 to 2
            one = time*0.5
            two = time*0.4
            score = one + two
            # Code populate dataframe with column time for one and two sub columns, 
            # and the score for the score column
            time += 1
        print("step %s " % i)
```

Picture of how the dataframe should look
[image: Dataframe]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor while specifying `index` and `columns`. The important point is to use [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) columns:

```
idx = pd.Index([f'step {i}' for i in range(1, 5)], name='time')
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(i, j) for i in range(-2, 3) for j in ('one', 'two')])

df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx, columns=cols)
```

You can then populate a value via [`pd.DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) for fast scalar setting by label:

```
df.at['step 1', (-2, 'two')] = 2
df.at['step 3', (0, 'one')] = 5

print(df)

         -2        -1         0         1         2     
        one  two  one  two  one  two  one  two  one  two
time                                                    
step 1  NaN    2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
step 2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
step 3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
step 4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Although jpp has already answered most of the part, I notice that there is another 'score; column you want.

```
arrays= [['score', -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2 ,2, 'score'],
        [None, 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names = ['time', None ])
df = pd.DataFrame(index = ['Step 1', 'Step 2', 'Step 3', 'Step 4', 'Step 5'], columns=columns)
df
time    score     -2          -1           0           1           2
        NaN      one   two    one   two   one   two   one   two   one   two
Step 1  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
Step 2  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
Step 3  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
Step 4  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
Step 5  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

It kinda feels like a hack